# Displaying Forem Gem generated default forum system in my application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm pretty new to ruby on rails. I'm trying to implement the Forem gem that I found.

https://github.com/radar/forem

I believe I installed it correctly...the problem is, I'm trying to display the default forum system in my application. I know this is such a newbie question but please help. Thank you.

Comment: Okay, so I installed everything correctly. I'm trying to "Display" the actual gem generated default forum into my application. For example, when I do rake routes | grep forem, it shows my forem/index path. This is what I want to display. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Just put that in-to your routes.rb file
`mount Forem::Engine, :at => '/forum'`

It will show forum at 'your-app.com/forum'. Replace `forum` with any path you want forem to shop up at.

Read the wiki here http://github.com/radar/forem